# Cannot build IONIC iOS --prod showing error

Tags: cordova, ionic2

I am able to build an ionic app. When I tried to build production version for iOS:

```
ionic cordova build ios --prod
```

It shows the below error:

> Error: ./src/app/main.ts
>       Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './app.module.ngfactory' in '/Users/karthikcp/Documents/IONIC/CIS/src/app'
>       resolve './app.module.ngfactory' in '/Users/karthikcp/Documents/IONIC/CIS/src/app'
>         using description file: /Users/karthikcp/Documents/IONIC/CIS/package.json (relative path: ./src/app)
>           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>         after using description file: /Users/karthikcp/Documents/IONIC/CIS/package.json (relative path: ./src/app)
>           using description file: /Users/karthikcp/Documents/IONIC/CIS/package.json (relative path: ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory)
>             no extension
>               Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>               /Users/karthikcp/Documents/IONIC/CIS/src/app/app.module.ngfactory doesn't exist
>             .ts
>               Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>               /Users/karthikcp/Documents/IONIC/CIS/src/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts doesn't exist
>             .js
>               Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>               /Users/karthikcp/Documents/IONIC/CIS/src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js doesn't exist
>             .json
>               Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>               /Users/karthikcp/Documents/IONIC/CIS/src/app/app.module.ngfactory.json doesn't exist
>             as directory
>               /Users/karthikcp/Documents/IONIC/CIS/src/app/app.module.ngfactory doesn't exist
>       [/Users/karthikcp/Documents/IONIC/CIS/src/app/app.module.ngfactory]
>       [/Users/karthikcp/Documents/IONIC/CIS/src/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts]
>       [/Users/karthikcp/Documents/IONIC/CIS/src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js]
>       [/Users/karthikcp/Documents/IONIC/CIS/src/app/app.module.ngfactory.json]
>       [/Users/karthikcp/Documents/IONIC/CIS/src/app/app.module.ngfactory]
>        @ ./src/app/main.ts 2:0-60
>           at BuildError.Error (native)
>           at new BuildError (/Users/karthikcp/Documents/IONIC/CIS/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/util/errors.js:16:28)
>           at callback (/Users/karthikcp/Documents/IONIC/CIS/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/webpack.js:121:28)
>           at emitRecords.err (/Users/karthikcp/Documents/IONIC/CIS/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:265:13)
>           at Compiler.emitRecords (/Users/karthikcp/Documents/IONIC/CIS/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:371:38)
>           at emitAssets.err (/Users/karthikcp/Documents/IONIC/CIS/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:258:10)
>           at applyPluginsAsyncSeries1.err (/Users/karthikcp/Documents/IONIC/CIS/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:364:12)
>           at next (/Users/karthikcp/Documents/IONIC/CIS/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:218:11)
>           at Compiler.compiler.plugin (/Users/karthikcp/Documents/IONIC/CIS/node_modules/webpack/lib/performance/SizeLimitsPlugin.js:99:4)
>           at Compiler.applyPluginsAsyncSeries1 (/Users/karthikcp/Documents/IONIC/CIS/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:222:13)

I am using the latest Ionic version When not using `--prod` then i am able to build it.. Please help me.. I am new to IONIC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by deleting `node_modules,package-lock.json`. Updated the package.json with:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "nightly",
    "typescript": "2.4.2"
  },
```

and re-run

> npm install